# Rename files with svn using wildcards

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, wildcard

Is it possible to change filenames in svn using wildcards?

for example: `svn rename *.ext1 *.ext2?`

or using Tortoisesvn?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. But you can use standard scripting tools with command-line Subversion to achieve what you want. Using PowerShell for example, this command changes the base name of every C# file in the current directory from `x` to `x_old`, noting that `svn mv` is the rename command in Subversion.

```
ls *.cs | % { svn mv $_.name ($_.name -replace ".cs", "_old.cs") }
```

From that starting point you can get more elaborate. `Get-ChildItem` (aka ls) provides a `-recurse` option so you can operate on an entire subtree, not just the current directory. (In that case you will need to use `$_.fullname` rather than `$_.name`, of course). For more sophisticated matching needs, you could go to regex matching with .NET using the `[regex]::Replace()` method instead of the `-replace` operator.

Comment: Well i expected svn to have a built in solution for this, but its a good idea. Thank you.